# Нужна ли запятая? Потому (,) что

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая: а делаем мы это (,) потому (,) что какими бы самовлюбленными ни были…

Я так понимаю это придаточное предложение. Или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Постановка запятой в большинстве случаев с "потому что" вариативна. Смотрите Розенталя [здесь](https://info.wikireading.ru/69359) или [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138).

Пример, похожий на Ваш:

*Он не пришёл, потому что заболел* — упор в сообщении делается на самый факт неявки, причина ее не уточняется; *Он не пришёл потому, что заболел* — на первый план выдвигается указание на причину неявки.

Аналогично и у Вас: если упор делается на сам факт того, что Вы что-то делаете, то запятая перед "потому", а если на причину, то перед "что".

Answer (score 0):

Здесь делается расчленение союза: **А делаем мы это потому, что какими бы самовлюбленными ни были…**

В этом предложении **логически выделена местоименная часть** союза ПОТОМУ ЧТО (**обозначение причины**), так как главное предложение **не является самостоятельным** с точки зрения семантики.

Это проявляется в том, что мы не можем убрать придаточную часть в связи с **перестройкой структуры** предложения (**инверсия** подлежащего и сказуемого в главной части).

Сравнить: А мы это делаем (самостоятельное предложение).